# How to check if a string contains certains letters/characters

Tags: java, string, syntax, char

If I want to check whether a String contains "CVR", "CPR" and "NR". How do I do so? I tried with following method but got some issues

```
String testString = "cpr1210";

if (testString.contains("cpr||cvr||nr")) {
    System.out.println("yes");
}
```

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: 1. You should mention what your issue is. 2. This is not a valid Java syntax. 3. Use `String.contains()` instead.

Comment: @Amongalen I tried with contains() but it does not detect the sequence of characters.

Comment: "cor1210" - doesn't contain any of the mentioned test sequences. Don't know what you expected.

Comment: @Amongalen What I meant is that even if I was to write a string with the letters, it still wont detect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might use `String#matches()` here, with a regex alternation:

```
String input = "cpr1210";
if (input.matches("(?i).*(?:cpr|cvr|nr).*")) {
    System.out.println("MATCH");
}
```

If you really wanted to use `String#contains()`, then you would need to have three separate calls to that method, for each sequence.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comment to your question, you may use `String#contains()`.

```
    String testString = "cor1210";
    // will not print yes, because none of the sequences fit
    if (testString.contains("cpr") || testString.contains("cvr") || testString.contains("nr")) {
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```

Make sure your logic-syntax in the if-clause is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether a String contains another String (a substring) with the `String.contains()` method. It returns a boolean value. Keep in mind that this method is case sensitive. If you want to do case-insensitive search then use the same technique, convert both input and search string in same case and then call the method.

```
    String testString = "cor1210";

    //checks whether testString contains CVR, CPR or NR
    if (testString.contains("CVR")||testString.contains("CPR")||testString.contains("NR")){
        System.out.println("yes");
    }
```